# find out how many people registered each day

Tags: mysql

In mySQL what I am trying to do is to query my table and find out how many people registered each day. In other words, I want to be able to produce the following output for one month:

```
1 January: 10 registrations
2 January: 150 registrations
3 January: 50  registrations

select created, regID
from registrations
```

Dates are in the following format in the DB: 2012-11-01 00:00:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get registration counts for each day of January, use this `select`:

```
select daymonth(registration_date), count(*)
from registrations
where registration_date >= '01/01/2012' and registration_date <= '01/31/2012'
group by daymonth(registration_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually use a grouping operator:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS registrations, DATE(created) AS created_date GROUP BY created_date
```

If `created` is already a `DATE` column, then the conversion isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT created, count(regID) FROM registrations GROUP BY created ORDER BY created ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   DATE(DATE_REGISTERED) DATE, COUNT(*) totalRegistered
FROM     tableName
GROUP BY DATE
```